# Таймеры в Android

Tags: android

Есть участок кода, нужно перезагрузить таймер при нажатии на кнопку. Чтобы при этом он ***НЕ*** тикнул. Помогите, пожалуйста, уже замучался.

Таймер:

```
timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){;

                    Rand();
                }
            });

        }
    }, 0, 2000);
```

После нажатия кнопки таймер должен перезагрузиться:

```
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.button:
    if (button1.getText() == String.valueOf(n1 + n2)) {
        result++;
        //вот тут его надо перезагрузить
        Rand();
    }
```

Comment: Вы имели ввиду "перезапустить"? Или что-то совсем другое?

Comment: Да, именно это я имел ввиду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так:

```
 class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{
       public void run()
       {
          Intent x =  new Intent(startClickActivity.this, ClickCountActivity.class);
          startActivity(x);
       }
    }

// Your code
MyTimerTask task = new MyTimerTask();
final long seconds = 5;
timer.schedule(task,seconds*1000L);
clicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
   public void onClick(View v) 
   {                                                                   
      counter++;
      task.cancel();
      task = new MyTimerTask();
      timer.schedule(task,seconds*1000L);
   }
});
```

Можно вообще так:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 TextView myCounter;
 Button btnStart;
 CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  myCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mycounter);
  btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
  btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

    //cancel the old countDownTimer 
    if(countDownTimer!=null){
     countDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

     @Override
     public void onFinish() {
      myCounter.setText("Finished!");
     }

     @Override
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
      myCounter.setText("Millisecond Until Finished: "
        + String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));
     }

    };

    countDownTimer.start();
   }
  });

 }

}
```

P.S. https://www.google.com/search?q=android+timer+with+restart